# Kotlin: functional programming, sealed class List

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, sealed-class

I am practicing some functional programming with a sealed class List and a map function.

So far the code for the sealed class

```
sealed class List <T> {

    class Node <T> ( val head : T , val tail : List<T>) : List<T> () {
        override fun toString () =
            "${head.toString()} , ${tail.toString()}"
    }

    object Nil : List<Nothing> ()  {
        override fun toString () = "NIL"
    }

    companion object {
        operator
        fun <T> invoke (vararg values : T ) : List<T>{
            val empty = Nil as List<T>
            val res = values.foldRight( empty , { v, l -> l.addFirst(v)   })
            return res
        }
    }

    fun addFirst ( head : T ) : List<T> = Node (head , this)

    fun removeFirst ()  : List <T> = when (this) {
        is Nil -> throw IllegalStateException()
        is Node<T> -> this.tail
    }

}
```

The map function ***inside*** the sealed class worked fine, but now I want it to run ***outside*** the sealed class like

```
fun <T,R> map (list:List<T>, f: (T) -> R) {
    when(list) {
        is List.Nil -> List.Nil as List<R>
        is List.Node -> List.Node<R> (f(head), tail.map(f))
    }
}
```

But now "head" and "tail" don't work any longer, because of unresolved references. I tried different strategies, but nothings works. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: `list.head`, `list.tail`?

Comment: This was my first choice. But with : 

is List.Node<T> -> List.Node<R> (f (list.head), list.tail.map (f))

map doesn't work any longer

Comment: Found a solution after some more research

fun <T,R> List<T>.map (f : (T) -> R) : List<R> = when (this) {
    List.Nil -> List.Nil as List<R>
    is List.Node -> List.Node (f(head), tail.map(f))
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution after some more research fun  List.map (f : (T) -> R) : List = when (this) { List.Nil -> List.Nil as List is List.Node -> List.Node (f(head), tail.map(f)) }